# In Linear Algebra exam, the transpose expression in my opinion is weird and wrong.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, transpose

Let
$$A=\left[\begin{matrix}1\ 2\ 3,&4\ 5\ 6,&7\ 8\ 9\\\end{matrix}\right]^T$$
be the A in the Transformation
$$T(x)=Ax$$
in my opinion its weird that it looks like ([1x3],[1x3],[1x3])^T
and doesn't make any sense, so i just asume that,
$$A=\left[\begin{matrix}1\ 2\ 3,&4\ 5\ 6,&7\ 8\ 9\\\end{matrix}\right]^T=\left[\begin{matrix}1&2&3\\4&5&6\\7&8&9\\\end{matrix}\right]^T=\left[\begin{matrix}1&4&7\\2&5&8\\3&6&9\\\end{matrix}\right]$$
since if they want, 
$$A=\left[\begin{matrix}\left[\begin{matrix}1\\2\\3\\\end{matrix}\right],&\left[\begin{matrix}4\\5\\6\\\end{matrix}\right],&\left[\begin{matrix}7\\8\\9\\\end{matrix}\right]\\\end{matrix}\right]^T=\left[\begin{matrix}1&2&3\\4&5&6\\7&8&9\\\end{matrix}\right]$$
which is normal, they should've put it as row like in the book,
$$A=\left[\begin{matrix}r_1&r_2&r_3\\\end{matrix}\right]^T=\left[\begin{matrix}r_1\\r_2\\r_3\\\end{matrix}\right]$$
So my question is, do you think if I disagree with the professor, he will consider it? or I'm just plain wrong ?

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm badly needing a second opinion before I try to humiliate myself infront of my Professor.

Comment: Welcome to the StackExchange Community. Can You please try to rephrase your question?

Comment: It looks to me like $$A=\begin{bmatrix}123\\456\\789\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Kumar I'm wondering what does the A=[123,456,789]^T means.